# How can I sort data on Mongodb

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb

Here is data from MongoDB

```
{
  "urls" : {
    "beauty-credit" : {
      "count" : 1,
      "keyword" : "beauty credit",
      "last_res" : 152,
      "last_sea" : "Sat May 13 2017 15:16:41 GMT+0700 (SE Asia Standard Time)",
      "url_site" : "beauty-credit"
    },
    "etude" : {
      "count" : 2,
      "keyword" : "etude",
      "last_res" : 1048,
      "last_sea" : "Sat May 13 2017 15:16:38 GMT+0700 (SE Asia Standard Time)",
      "url_site" : "etude"
    },
    "skinfood" : {
      "count" : 2,
      "keyword" : "skinfood",
      "last_res" : 478,
      "last_sea" : "Sat May 13 2017 15:16:45 GMT+0700 (SE Asia Standard Time)",
      "url_site" : "skinfood"
    }
  }
}
```

and Here is my code. Now I filter only last_res > 10

```
function gotData(data){
        result = data.val() 
        const urls_kws = Object.keys(result)
                        .filter(key => result[key].last_res > 10)
}
```

How can I sort data by "count"?  Also how can I show only 30 rows?

Comment: You could sort and limit your collection.

Comment: Is it an option to change the database schema and turn the `urls` objects into an array? You could then use an aggregation pipeline with `unwind`. Using data as field-names is an anti-pattern. You really shouldn't do that if possible. MongoDB offers you far more query-tools when you use arrays.

Answer (score 0):

In order to sort the data by count you can use the sort() function from javascript with a custom comparator like

```
 urls_kws.sort((a, b) => a.count - b.count)
```

In order to now get only the first 30 values, you can then slice the array

```
 var short_urls_kws = urls_kws.slice(0, 30)
```

Comment: `var urls_kws = urls_kws.sort((a, b) => a.count - b.count)` I have add this code but result still not sort by count

Comment: `var urls_kws_sort = urls_kws.sort((a, b) => a.count - b.count)` I try this, but it same

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it retrieves the untruncated dataset from the database. When it's a large collection, then this may take a while. It would be better to do this on the database.